# sending data from $.ajax to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send the username to `php` using `ajax`.

Here is my `js`.

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dbquery.php",
        data: username,
        success: function(result){
            $("#dbdata").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is php.

```
$value = $_GET['username'];
```

I know it is about the `ajax` because everything worked fine when the `ajax` part was written in pure `javascript`.

Comment: send data as JSON object as :  `data: {"username" : username}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all your ajax type is post but you getting value using GET[] This is mistake here.

try this

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
var username = $("#username").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dbquery.php",
    data: {'username':username},
    success: function(result){
        $("#dbdata").html(result);
    }
}); });
```

and you have to use this to get value

```
$value = $_POST['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Send `data` as an object as `$_GET` reads associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters

```
data: {username:username},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `type:"POST"` and trying to retrieve the values in GET Array in the PHP code .Change the method to `GET`

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "dbquery.php",
        data: username,
        success: function(result){
            $("#dbdata").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
var dataString = 'username ='+ encodeURIComponent(username) ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dbquery.php",
        data: dataString ,
        success: function(result){
            $("#dbdata").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You are using POST in ajax. and GET in PHP, which is wrong.

> If we use POST then in the PHP file, we use $_POST[”] to get the
>   value. If we use GET then we use $_GET[]

**Second:** data is passed as an object as `data: {username: username}`. This means that if we use `$_POST[‘username’]` in the PHP file, we will get the value of the username.
Your final code will be

**AJAX**

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dbquery.php",
        data: {username:username},
        success: function(result){
            $("#dbdata").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$value = $_POST['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pass data as an Object. To access data in PHP you have to use $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] etc

```
    $('#username').blur(function(){
        var data = {
            username:$("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dbquery.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(result){
                $("#dbdata").html(result);
            }
        });
    })
```